# Where can I download John Shipman's skip list python implementation?

Tags: python, skip-lists

Following a suggestion elsewhere on stack overflow, I've looked over John Shipman's [excellent article](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/lang/python/examples/pyskip/web/index.html) on skip lists and the documentation on his python implementation. The code is all there, but it's broken up into snippets for explanatory purposes. That's great for the web page, but I'd rather not have to extract the files from there. Every link I've found points to that same page.

`pip install pyskip` installs some other implementation. I don't know where else to look.

Comment: https://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/projects/pystyler/skiplist.py ?

Comment: Do you actually want Shipman's implementation, which was written to teach you how to write a skiplist, and hasn't been updated since originally written, and probably hasn't been optimized or tested or used in any serious projects? Is something wrong with the (at least) 3 implementations on PyPI?

Comment: As far as I can see none of the ones on pypi or on code.google has the capacity to take a key function and a compare function as parameters when creating the list. 

Thanks for the link to the source module. We're going to make whatever updates it needs to work properly on Python 3.4. If we get permission from nmt we will, of course, share our updates.